# Обработка формы аяксом

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Пример страницы</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
                    <label for="type_work">Тип заказа</label>
                        <select id="type_work" class="sel form-control" name="type_work">
                            <option value="copyright">Копирайтинг</option>
                            <option value="rewrite">Рерайтинг</option>
                            <option value="special">Спецзаказ</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="special_thematic" id="special_thematic">
                            <label for="special_thematic_id">Спецтематика</label>
                            <select id="special_thematic_id" class="sel form-control" name="special_thematic_id">
                                <option value="6">Украинский копирайт</option>
                                <option value="7">Английский копирайт</option>
                                <option value="8">Французский копирайт</option>
                                <option value="9">Украинский рерайт</option>
                                <option value="10">Английский рерайт</option>
                                <option value="11">Французский рерайт</option>
                                <option value="20">Стихотворение</option>
                                <option value="21">Написание сказки</option>
                                <option value="22">Немецкий копирайт</option>
                                <option value="23">Немецкий рерайт</option>
                                <option value="25">Исследования/аналитика</option>
                                <option value="26">Продающие статьи</option>
                                <option value="27">Пресс-релизы</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type_work').change( function () {
        if ($(this).val != 'special') {
            $('#special_thematic_id').removeAttr('name');
            $('#special_thematic').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('#special_thematic_id').attr('name', 'special_thematic_id');
            $('#special_thematic').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

Как сделать, чтоб блок special_thematic был виден только при выборе "Спецзаказ", а во всех остальных случаях значение его name обнулялось (чтоб в $_POST не передавалось его значение)? И главное, чтоб display:none/block и name изменялись при перевыборе типа заказ (change).

Comment: `$(this).val` -> `$(this).va()`

Comment: `$('#special_thematic').hide()`/`show()`

Comment: По-конкретнее пожалуйста по-поводу $(this).val -> $(this).va(), вторую часть с hide/show понял.

Comment: Только не `.va()`, a `.val()`. "Поконкретнее" есть в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: `jQuery().val` - это функция, а не свойство.